# Print 2-d array in sprial order-entering infinite loop

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to implement print 2 d array in sprial order. I dont know why but my code is entering inside infinite for loop prints 1,2,3,4 repeatedly.

StringsubString.java

```
package com.String;

public class StringSubString {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        int[][] values = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}};
        printInSprialOrder(values, 4, 4);
    }

    private static void printInSprialOrder(int A[][], int m, int n) {
        int t = 0, b = m - 1, l = 0, r = n - 1;
        while (t <= b && l <= r) {
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
                System.out.println(A[t][i]);
                t++;
            }
            for (int i = t; i <= b; i++) {
                System.out.println(A[i][r]);
                r--;
            }

            for (int i = r; i >= l; i++) {
                System.out.println(A[b][i]);
                b--;
            }
            for (int i = b; i >= t; i--) {
                System.out.println(A[i][l]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siKFOI8PNKM

Comment: If your code is printing 1, 2, 3, 4 repeatedly, then you've posted something different from your code.  It behaves totally differently when I run it.

Comment: With this code I am getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:" 4, So please check once at your end, may be you can debug it, then You will find the problem on your own. Although its a very common problem, you can serach it google and can have lot of approaches and solutions.

Comment: @pbajpai21 When run the same program in another system now it shows 1
6
11
16 and an exception .quite unexpected behaviour as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code behaved differently from what you mentioned here.
Try:

```
 while(t<b && l<r){

        for(int i=l; i<= r ; i++){
            System.out.println(A[t][i]);
        }
        t++;

        for(int i=t;i<=b;i++){
            System.out.println(A[i][r]);
        }
        r--;

        for(int i=r ; i>=l ; i--){
            System.out.println(A[b][i]);
        }
        b--;

        for(int i=b;i>=t;i--){
            System.out.println(A[i][l]);
        }
        l++;

}
```

Comment: This is not my expected output.. I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siKFOI8PNKM so the output I want is 1 2 3 4 8 12 16..

Answer (score 2):

After the first for loop, you have `t=4`, then in the second for loop, you will print nothing. And then, in the third for loop, your index i increase, so, it will try to print `A[4][2]` which is out of bound of the array.